# Rails: List of users who upvoted a model (pin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, vote

So I have a basic rails app where users can upvote a pin - Now I would like to show a list of user who upvoted the pin  the view (app/views/pins/show.html.erb)

**app/models/user.rb**

```
  has_many :pins    
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :upvoted_pins, through: :votes, source: :pin
```

**app/models/pin.rb**

```
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :upvoted_users, through: :votes, source: :user
```

**app/controllers/pins_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @disable_nav = true
    @pin = Pin.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @pin.upvoted_users

  end
```

Then i added the code to render who upvoted the pins in app/views/pins/show.html.erb

```
<ul><li><%= @pin.upvoted_users %></li></ul>
```

But it shows an association error when I load the page:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_User:0x007fddde186370>
```

Which is strange because When I inspect @pin.upvoted_users in my rails console I get the users who upvoted the pin correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [lazy loading](http://rubyinrails.com/2014/01/what-is-lazy-loading-in-rails/).

To list users, you can use a loop, eg:

```
<ul>
  <% @pin.upvoted_users.each do |user| %>
    <li><%= user.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks I find out minutes ago, I mark you answer as correct ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

In case someone is facing the same issue, it was a stupid mistake of myself:
You can render the list of users who upvoted the pins like this:

```
<% @pin.upvoted_users.each do |user| %>
      <ul><li><%= user.name %></li></ul>
    <% end %>
```